# What's going on with the Google Knowledge Graph API?

Tags: google-api, google-knowledge-graph

I have used the knowledge graph API before and it worked fine. I tried to access it today and it gives me no results at all. Here is my sample request and response.

GET Request:

```
https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=taylor+swift&key=MY_API_KEY&limit=1&indent=True
```

Response:

```
{
"@context": {
"@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
"goog": "http://schema.googleapis.com/",
"EntitySearchResult": "goog:EntitySearchResult",
"detailedDescription": "goog:detailedDescription",
"kg": "http://g.co/kg"
},
"@type": "ItemList",
"itemListElement": []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working now : http://knowledge-graph.fr/
I confirm there was an issue with the API.

You can also try it here in Google Developer Console : [https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=fr#p/kgsearch/v1/kgsearch.entities.search?query=taylor+swift&_h=1&](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=fr#p/kgsearch/v1/kgsearch.entities.search?query=taylor%20swift&_h=1&)